# Acessando os valores de uma lista 3D em Python

Tags: python, array, lista, arraylist

Eu estou com uma questão que não estou encontrando uma resposta que não seja por uma estrutura de repetição: como acessar valores numa lista 3D.
Eu tenho uma lista que é uma pilha de 400 imagens de dimensão 2304x2304 pixel, **(400, 2304, 2304)**.
Eu gostaria de selecionar um dado pixel, exemplo o 10x10 e acessar todos os valores desse pixel ao longo das 400 imagens. Eu havia tentado algo como `vpixel = img[:][10][10]`. Na minha ideia, a variável `vpixel` deveria ter 400 posições, porém está gerando uma variável com 2304 posições. Em uma estrutura de repetição eu consigo, pois eu fixo o pixel que eu quero e faço um `for` de 0 a 399 daí eu tenho todos os valores.
Mas eu queria uma maneira que não fosse necessário um for para tal, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score -2):

Eu mesmo acabei encontrando a resposta. Eu transformei minha lista em um `np.array(img)` e acessei pelo método `vpixel = img[:, 10, 10]` e funcionou!!!!